# Jquery Date picker is Selecting today and default date given

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery date picker for selecting a date, and I'd like to be able to default the selection to a given date.

Here's my code:

```
var SelectDate=new Date(2013, 06,25 , 0, 0, 0, 0) ;
$("#OnwardTravelDate").datepicker({ 
      numberOfMonths: 2, 
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
      minDate: datePickMinDate_DT, 
      maxDate: datePickMaxDate_DT, 
      defaultDate: SelectDate 
});
```

But the date selector control highlights both today's date and the date 'selectDate' . I want only 'selectDate' as highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeClass("ui-state-highlight");` should fix your problem.

but if you just want the highlight of today never show again, you may get the datepicker's source (`jquery.ui.datepicker.js`) and find this line to remove:

`(printDate.getTime() == today.getTime() ? ' ui-state-highlight' : '') +`

then compile it to use.

Comment: It's actually the ui-state-hover which is causing the date to appear different for me, and I have no idea why on instantiation it is deciding to add the hover class to today's date. As soon as I move my mouse over, today's date becomes normal and the hover effect works as it should for all the dates. This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the `value` of `#OnwardTravelDate` in html **or** jquery?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="OnwardTravelDate" value="25/06/2013" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#OnwardTravelDate").val("25/06/2013"); // Before datepicker code
```

Then you don't need your `defaultDate: SelectDate` at all :)

Hope that helps.

---

**Edit**: (more info)

You could also try the `setDate` method:

```
$("#OnwardTravelDate").datepicker("setDate", SelectDate); // After datepicker code
```

---

Edit: jsfidle

This JS fidle seems to work for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrgbL/2/)

Maybe the styling on your theme makes it look like it's selected?

Comment: no its not in the textbox but in the datepicker control i want only one date highlighted but now always highlights todays date along with the date i had given

Comment: Please Read the above comment

Comment: surely setDate works, but today is still highlighted, that is the problem.

Comment: @Santo yes, overwrite `.ui-state-highlight` or remove it is the solution. but there is noting to do with defaultDate or setDate since _Sreerejith S S_ never said they don't work

Comment: @Santo you can check my answer, I think remove the dynamically class adding in jquery-ui is better. then today won't be highlighted anymore.

Comment: @leonhart,@mishik As because i am using jquery.ui.1.8 version, I didnt find the above code ,But i deleted the 'ui-state-highlight' Part and it works fine. Any way thanks for the advise . that helps me alot

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker assigns different classes to "today" and "selected day":

today - ui-state-highlight

selected day - ui-state-active

You can either remove or override styling of ".ui-datepicker .ui-state-highlight" or remove the class:

```
$("#OnwardTravelDate a.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT1:** From [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-how-not-to-highlight-current-day) I found just a fix, but I'm not able to handle with your code.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) {       
       window.setTimeout(function(){
           $(inst.dpDiv).find('.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-hover').removeClass('ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover')      
       },0)     
   },   
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/kn2jG/) and if possible update it with your code you trying.

**EDIT2:** By overriding the default css `.ui-datepicker-today` and `a.ui-state-highlight` of with the below one.

```
.ui-datepicker-today a.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(/themeroller/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #555555;    
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/nYzpy/1/)